# jquery function if span exists

Tags: jquery, function

How can I create a function in which it validates whether a "span" element exists under a div class?

For example :

```
<div class="myDiv">

</div
```

it doesn't have `<span>` under `.myDiv`. So validate if span exists or not. Show "span exists" in console.log if it exists, and "span does not exists" if not.

Thanks!

Comment: `($(".myDiv span").length() > 0)`

Comment: i already tried that but i also want to display if it doesn't exists

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.length` property to check this

```
function spanExists(){
  return $(".myDiv span").length() > 0;
}
```

Now you can use this function to check if `span` exists under `.myDiv`.

Answer (score 2):

I created two alternatives to make it clear:

```js
// quick answer
console.log(($(".myDiv1 span").length == 0 ? 'does not ' : '') + 'exists')
console.log(($(".myDiv2 span").length == 0 ? 'does not ' : '') + 'exists')

// slow but more detailed
function checkSpanExists(element) {
    let exists = ($(element+" span").length == 0)
    if (exists) {
        console.log('element '+element+' does not contain span');
    } else {
        console.log('element '+element+' contains span')
    }
}

checkSpanExists('.myDiv1');
checkSpanExists('.myDiv2');
```

```html
<!doctype html>
  <html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Mastering Javascript</title>
      <script
          src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
          integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="myDiv1">

      </div>
      <div class="myDiv2">
          <span>mastering javascript</span>
      </div>
      <script>

      </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

if you still need help feel free to ask for improvements...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
 if( $('.myDiv').has("span"))        
    {
         console.log("span exists");
    } else {
         console.log("span does not exist");
    }
```

Comment: what if I don't use IDs for span because I will use it for many spans

Comment: are you just trying to check if any span at all exists inside div, not any specific one?

Comment: yes and i tried your lines of code but I only get the display if it exists but if it doesn't exists it do not display the "span does not exists"

Answer (score 0):

Wanna display something? This display a string if spans exist, and also display another if no spans exist.

```js
$(function(){
  if($('.myDiv span').length > 0){
      $('#status').text('One or more spans exist.');
  }else{
      $('#status').text("No span exists.");
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">

</div>

<div id="status"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through all divs and check how many child span is found:

```js
$("div").each(function(){
  console.log("Div "+$(this).attr("class")+" has "+$(this).find("span").length+" span(s)");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="myDiv1">
  <a href="#">Link</a>
</div>

<div class="myDiv2">
  <span>Span</span>
</div>

<div class="myDiv3">
  <h1>Header</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I have question, how can I filter divs that has spans and doesn't. 

For example I have three divs, i want to check if that div has a span or does not.

Comment: What do you mean by "filter"? A filter is something that will keep a type of things, and discard the rest. So you would have a result for divs having spans (for example). I suppose you want a list... Or maybe highlight them with a color?

Comment: i used each function in the spans already. I am trying to loop all the divs and check if it has span or not

Comment: Haha... I had that exact idea too... Look at my edit. ;)

Answer (score 0):

All the answers gave a solution using `jQuery` so I said why not make it only using pure `JavaScript` because I think such tasks doesn't really requires `jQuery`'s power.

Try this:

making a function that receives an element, or a string representing the element's id and then see if that element does contain a span in it.

```
function doesContainSpan(element) {
    var el = (typeof element == 'string') ? document.getElementById(element):element, elementChildren = el.children, l = elementChildren.length, i = 0;
    for(; i < l; i++) {
        if(elementChildren[i].nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'span' {
            console.log('the element with ID = ' + el.id + ' has a span tag');
            return true;
        }
    }
    console.log('the element with ID = ' + el.id + ' doesn't have a span tag');
    return false;
}
```

You can send it a div with class `.myDiv` as you said like this:

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('myDiv')[0];
doesContainSpan(el);
```

It's possible to make the function fetch the element with a given `class` instead of the `ID` when sending a string as the parameter, here it will represent the `class` not the `ID`,  by changing this:

```
el = (typeof element == 'string') ? document.getElementById(element):element
```

into this:

```
el = (typeof element == 'string') ? document.getElementsByClassName(element)[0]:element
```